# how to allow the service layer to manage multiple repository layers during insertion

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, service-layer, aggregates

Folks,
The problem statement can be found as follows,
Background:

1. the application collect user information, which can be modeled by AggregateA, and AggregateB;
2. AggregateA contains a collection of AggregateB
3. AggregateA/B contains a small number of Entities
4. the application persists AggregateA then AggregateB (the primary key of AggregateA is used an input to persist AggregateB)

Question:
in the service layer, is there any alternative to this?

```
def add_user_info(varA, varB):
    A_ID = repoA.add(varA)
    repoA.commit()
    repoB.add(A_ID, varB)
    repoB.commit()
```

is it possible to have a single commit in this insertion?

Comment: You should have a single commit for both repository operations, please consider using the unit-of-work pattern (general concept is having a single-instance session object encapsulated by each repository object and by unit-of-work object).

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use an Unit of Work pattern.

```py
def add_user_info(varA, varB):
    A_ID = repoA.add(varA)
    repoB.add(A_ID, varB)
    uow.commit()
```

This way, you'll also avoid side effects turning all the procedure an single operation, and if it's fails, the repoA won't generate trash in your database.

An example of UoW [here](https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/chapter_06_uow.html)